# How to show Circular Progress Indicator until value is loaded?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Widget which on first click shows error page that value that I am trying to reach is null... When I open that Widget second time then it works because on first click the value is loaded and screen is showed properly. How can I achieve that user sees Circular Progress Indicator instead of error page until value is loaded?

This is the Widget:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    user.cacheGet();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Last Conversation"),
      ),
      body: user.conversationID.values == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Container(
              child: _myListView(context, user.conversationID.values),
            ),
    );
  }
```

This shows error because `user.conversationID.values` is `null`. It is loaded through `cacheGet( )` function which has type `Future <bool>`... So if I go back and open same screen (widget) again then that value is loaded and no error is shown. I tried to use ternary operator but in this case it does not work.

**EDIT**

This is `cacheGet` function.

```
  Future<bool> cacheGet() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    var body = jsonEncode({"token": token, "userID": this.firebaseUser.uid});
    var res = await http.post((baseUrl + "/cacheGet"), body: body, headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    });

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      this.conversationID = Conversations.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Business logic should not be done in the `build` method. Look at `FutureBuilder`. You need to share what `cacheGet` is.

Comment: I've edited my question. But it is not relevant. It's just a json returned from backend.

Comment: Why bother returning a `bool` if you're not going to using it? Why don't you just return the `Conversations` object that's actually useful? It's poor design to be forced to call this method and get the relevant data from a different place.

Comment: Ok. I'll consider that. Thanks!

Comment: If you change your function to return the data you need, it'll be easier to use `FutureBuilder`.What "error" are you getting. You mentioned that you got one but you don't specify what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap your widget with future builder. Here is an sample code:

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: user.cacheGet(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return user.conversationID.values == null
                ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
                : Container(
              child: _myListView(context, user.conversationID.values),
            );
          }else{
            return Container();
          }
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely a routine like `user.cacheGet();` should not be done inside `build()`, but probably `initState()` would be a better place for it.

I recommend looking at [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) (or [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)).  Think about how your value is likely a *Future*, then your build routine will use `FutureBuilder` that will show the `CircularProgressIndicator()` while it is waiting for data, and then whatever else you want once you have the data (or the third case is that there was an error fetching the data).  The future should be initialized in `initState()`.

Comment: I'm using Provider as state management which requires context argument. That's why I'm doing it in build.

Comment: @harunB10 `BuildContext` is available outside of `build`.

Comment: You can access [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) from `initState` -- I recommend `context.read<T>()`.